# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'message_board'

Tags: python-3.x

I ran this command on the terminal

```
coverage run test_message_board_urls.py
```

and I got an error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'message_board

I have a statement in the `test_message_board_urls.py` file that says

```
from message_board.views import xxx,yyy,zzz
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It does look for the module message_board in order to import the functions xxx, yyy and zzz from the package views, but it does not find the module message_board. Either you have not installed the module message_board or it is located at a path, where it is not found by the script.

Comment: How to I make sure the script can locate the path?

Thank you for answering me.

Comment: First of all, you need to check, if the PYTHONPATH is added the system path. Then the module should be found, if it is installed relative to the python path by pip or conda or something similar. Otherwise, if you have downloaded the module to a certain folder, you should refer to it in the import either by a relative or an absolute path.

Comment: I did that and it actually worked. Thank you very much.